# how to mount jdk in volume and use it in a container while creating a docker image

Tags: docker, volumes

### I am creating a Docker Image from a Dockerfile ,below is the data inside Dockerfile

FROM centos

ADD jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /opt/java

ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java/jdk-11.0.7
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/java/jdk-11.0.7/bin 
RUN ls -l /opt/java/jdk-11.0.7
RUN java -version
ADD build/libs/CatalogModel-1.0.jar CatalogModel-1.0.jar
EXPOSE 9081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "CatalogModel-1.0.jar"]

---

Docker while creating image from Dockerfile will extract the jdk inside jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz which is present parallel to Dockerfile.Instead of directly adding the jdk-11.0.7_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz file in each and evry image i want to mount it in a volume so that it can be used while creating other images also.

Comment: Docker doesn't really work that way.  Volumes are for persisting data, not sharing code or language runtimes.  You can build an image that contains your JDK and then build other images `FROM` the image you built, or use something prebuilt like the [Docker Hub `openjdk` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk).

Comment: Suppose i create an image containing only this jdk and nothing else,then can i save it in a volume and use that volume while creating other images which require jdk? Like the dockerfile i have mentioned it needs jdk!

Comment: You can use that image in a `FROM` line in other images.  Volumes don't fit into this use case at all.

Answer (score -1):

1. create a container from any image `docker run -it -d --name jdk_container initial-image`
2. copy jdk into that container using docker cp command
3. create image from that container using command `docker create container-id new-image-name`
4. create container from this newly build image. it will contain your jdk.